# How would I write a loop for this invariant?

Tags: java, invariants

These are assertions for an algorithm to find the minimum of an array b[h.k]:

```
Precondition: h <= k < b.length
Postcondition: b[x] is the minimum of b[h...k]
```

Is this the correct loop for this invariant?

invariant: b[x] is the minimum of b[h...t]

```
int x = t;    int t = h;
// {inv: b[x] is the minimum of b[h...t]}
while (t != k) {
   t = t+1;
   if (b[t] < b[x])
      { x = t;}
}
```

Comment: This smells like homework, so let's see what you have so far

Comment: How would you manually find the minimum number given a list of numbers?

Comment: @KshitijMehta, this is what I have so far.  Could you please provide feedback?

Comment: that's almost perfect. Just one minor correction... add `x = t;` before your while loop

Comment: the while loop works just as well as the for loop. Oh, forgot to mention one more correction: you should also add `t = h;` before you start the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the minimum of an array this way (pseudocode):

```
// assume b.length > 0
min = b[0]
for i=1 to b.length
  if b[i] < min
    min = b[i]
```

To restrict it to `b[h, ..., k]`:

```
min = b[h]
for i=h+1 to k
  if b[i] < min
    min = b[i]
```

So you basically just change the upper and lower bound of the loop

Since `h<=k<b.length`, `b[h]` is valid and executing the loop from the next element until `k` iterates over the reqiured elements (if `h==k`, the loop is empty)

UPDATE: as you are consistently failing with the implementation of the pseudocode into java, I'll translate it for you:

```
// assume: int b[]; int h; int k; h<=k<=b.length and b.length>0
// find min == b[i] such that b[i]<=b[j] for all h<=j<=k
int min = b[h];
for (int i=h+1; i<k; i=i+1) {
  if (b[i] < min) {
    min = b[i];
  }
}
// here: min contains the (first) minimum element within b[h, ..., k]
```

Note: you could write `i=i+1` as `++i` as well

Comment: If I wanted to restrict it to b[h..s-1], would I still say min = b[h], and then for i=h+1 to s-1?  And the if statement would still be the same?

Comment: Everything stays the same, except replace `k` with `s-1`.  You need to ensure when executing that code that `h<=s-1` still holds

Comment: Thank you.  Also, in the first for loop, why are you starting i at 1.  Shouldn't it be i = 0?

Comment: You could start at 0, but we already processed that element in `min=b[0]`, so the `if` would be false (`b[0] < b[0]`) and thus skipped

Comment: I do not know -- you wrote `h` to `k` first, then `h` to `t` in your question, `t` does not appear in my answer

Comment: In your updated question the loop is incorrect: 1) you do not initialize `min`; 2) you start from `0` and go until `b.length`; 3) you compare `k` (a limit) to an element of the array; 4) you increment `h` (a limit) that you do not even use for any other reason; 5) you do not calculate minimum anywhere

Comment: See updated answer -- btw, it would be much better for you if you tried to compile your code before asking if it is correct: the compiler would have told you about many of the (syntax) errors you made