# Is the following loop correct for the invariant?

Tags: java, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I write a loop for this invariant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202004/how-would-i-write-a-loop-for-this-invariant)

Is the following for loop correct for the invariant? 
invariant: b[x] is the minimum of b[h...s-1]

```
 int x = h;      int h = s-1;

    // {inv: b[x] is the minimum of b[h...s-1]}
    while (s-1 != k) {
       s = s-1;
       if (b [s-1] < b[x])
          { x = s-1;}
    }
```

Comment: You should at least try compiling your code before posting it here!

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? Try also rewrite your code, because `s-1 = h` is an invalid expression in Java. Assignment can only be done right to left, i.e. `h = s - 1` would be okay.

Comment: I'm sorry..I'm new to Java, and I don't know how to do that yet.  I'm just doing this on paper.

Comment: And yet another reason why Java should not be used for teaching (no easy-access to a [good] REPL)...

Comment: It should be something like 
`int minimum = b[h] ;
for ( int i = h ; i < s ; i ++ )
   if ( b[i] < minimum )
       minimum = b[i] ;
`

Comment: Also, I think your calssmate already asked the same question. Check the answers that he got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202004/how-would-i-write-a-loop-for-this-invariant

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find the minimum of an array, you can do it like this.

```
int b[] = {1,3,2,5,2,3};

//min needs to have a starting value so b[0] works fine.
int min = b[0];

//This loops over the remaining elements in the array. If it finds a value smaller than the current minimum, it reassigns min to that value.
for(int i = 1; i < b.length; i++)
{
     if(b[i] < min)
          min = b[i];
}

//If you haven't covered for loops yet, here is how you can do it with a while.
int i = 1;
while(i < b.length)
{
     if(b[i] < min)
          min = b[i];
     i++;
}

//b.length is just a way of getting the length of an array.
```